# How to add only one quantity of one product in cart in opencart website

Tags: opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0. I want to add only one quantity of one product in a cart and if somebody tries to add same product in cart which is already in cart, Then there should be custom message on screen.

Comment: For that you have to do custom code on ocmod or vqmod

Comment: No need to do custom code got solution and it is...  $match = false;
       foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
         if ($product['product_id'] == $product_info['product_id']) {
            $match = true;
            break;
         }
       }  This check should in public function add() after $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id); and then you can check value of $match any where in add function.